# Convolution of the delta distribution, basic property

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I am trying to prove that  for all $\phi \in S(\mathbb{R}), \phi*\delta = \phi$. I tried with a direct calculation of $ \phi*\delta(\psi)$. At the very end, I got (expanding convolution and exchange the order of the integral, where $\tilde{\phi}(y-x) = \phi(x-y)$
$$
\int \delta(y)(\tilde{\phi} * \psi)(y) dy
$$
But I am not sure if it's legitimate to write the above integral as
$$
T(\tilde{\phi} * \psi) = T_{\phi}(\psi)
$$
Or is there another way to show this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly finished. Note that by definition of the delta distribution it holds that
$$\langle \phi*\delta,\psi\rangle = \int (\phi*\delta)(x) \psi(x) dx = \int \int \underbrace{\phi(x-y)}_{\tilde{\phi}(y-x):=} \delta(y) \psi(x) dy dx = \int \delta(y)(\tilde{\phi}*\psi)(y)dy =\langle \delta, \tilde{\phi}*\psi\rangle =  (\tilde{\phi}*\psi)(0) = \int \phi(x) \psi(x) dx = \langle \phi,\psi\rangle,$$
where the second to last step follows since inserting 0 just gives you this integral. Note that I use $\langle .,.\rangle$ as a notation for the integral. Since this equality holds for all test functions $\psi$, you get $\phi*\delta=\phi$.

Comment: In my book, I don not have the first equality given to me. I think this is what I need to show.

Comment: Oh I thought that you said you have already shown that part, I will add it to my answer in a minute.

Comment: Ok now I added the missing part.

Comment: on the second line, we end up with (̃ ∗)(0). Is that because (0)=1 and 0 otherwise? I think this is the part I am confusing about. Since in the previous line, we are doing integration and  is part of the integration. How can we just plug in values into an integration.

Comment: Is that because  is only meaningful at 0 and this eliminate the integral sign?

Comment: The delta distribution is, as stated in the name, not a function in the 'normal' sense, i.e. a function living on $\mathbb{R}$ for example. It is a function that is defined as $\delta(\phi)=\int \delta \phi dx=\phi(0)$ for all test functions, we say that this equality holds in the sense of distributions. We say that $\delta$ is only meaningful at 0 since we can approximate it by the function $$f_\varepsilon(x)=\begin{cases} 0, ~|x|>\varepsilon \\ \frac{1}{2\varepsilon},~|x|\leq \varepsilon \end{cases}$$ in the sense of distribution, i.e. the convergence holds for all test functions when

Comment: integrating, if you let $\varepsilon\to 0$ in the definition of $f$, you essentially get a function that is '$\infty$ at 0 and 0 everywhere else', although this interpretation is mathematically not really correct. If you want to learn more about the delta distribution, you can look all I said up on wikipedia or just ask here.